# Terraform with Cisco ACI - Associate Contract to EPG - Invalid Index

Tags: terraform, cisco, hcl

Still fairly new with programming, and diving into the deep end of terraform. I am working through learning ACI with Terraform and getting a error.  I think i am just declaring my objects wrong, but can't figure it out. i have tried to leave out a lot of redundant config and errors for brevity.

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../modules/tenant/contracts.tf line 38, in resource "aci_epg_to_contract" "terraform_epgweb_contract":
│   38:     application_epg_dn = aci_application_epg.epga[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aci_application_epg.epga is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "terraform_three"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Problem:
Assign 3 contracts, to each EPG (2 epgs in each App profile).

For App A that I created, I have epga which consists of a Web_EPG and DB EPG.
For App B that I created, I have epgb which consists of a Web_EPG and DB EPG.

```
module "my_tenant" {
   source                = "../modules/tenant"
   epga = {
    web_epg = {
      name                = "web_epg"
      application_profile = "app_a_ap"
      bridge_domain       = "app_a_bd"
    },
    db_epg = {
      name                = "db_epg"
      application_profile = "app_a_ap"
      bridge_domain       = "app_a_bd"
    }
   }
```

For the contracts I am using two different epg contracts - epga_contracts and epgb_contracts.

```
 epga_contracts = {
    terraform_one = {
          epg           = "web_epg",
          contract      = "contract_sql",
          contract_type = "consumer" 
        },
    terraform_two = {
          epg           = "db_epg",
          contract      = "contract_sql",
          contract_type = "provider" 
    },
    terraform_three = {
          epg           = "web_epg",
          contract      = "contract_web",
          contract_type = "provider" 
    }
  }
```

to assign them i am trying to loop through both of the web contracts and both of the db contracts that are already created to assign them to the EPG's

```
resource "aci_epg_to_contract" "terraform_epgweb_contract" {
    for_each           = var.epga_contracts
    application_epg_dn = aci_application_epg.epga[each.key].id
    contract_dn        = aci_contract.terraform_contract[each.value.contract].id
    contract_type      = each.value.contract_type
}

resource "aci_epg_to_contract" "terraform_epgdb_contract" {
    for_each           = var.epga_contracts
    application_epg_dn = aci_application_epg.epgb[each.key].id
    contract_dn        = aci_contract.terraform_contract[each.value.contract].id
    contract_type      = each.value.contract_type
}
```

lastly here is the map for the contract.

```
variable "epgb_contracts" {
  type = map(object({
    epg = string,
    contract  = string,
    contract_type = string,
  }))
  description = "Map of filters to create and their associated subjects"
  default     = {}
}
```

Defintion of epga

```
resource "aci_application_epg" "epga" {
  for_each               = local.epga
  name                   = each.value.name
  application_profile_dn = aci_application_profile.app_prof[each.value.application_profile].id
  relation_fv_rs_bd      = aci_bridge_domain.bd[each.value.bridge_domain].id
  depends_on             = [aci_bridge_domain.bd, aci_application_profile.app_prof]
}
```

here is the directory tree

```
/Users/jasonholt/terraform/mod_examples
├── aci_tenant
│   ├── credentials.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   ├── terraform.tfstate.backup
│   └── variables.old
└── modules
    └── tenant
        ├── app_profile.tf
        ├── bd.tf
        ├── contracts.tf
        ├── epg.tf
        ├── locals.tf
        ├── tenant.tf
        ├── variables.tf
        └── vrf.tf
```

Comment: What is the definition of `aci_application_epg.epga`?

Comment: Please update your question with properly formated new code, not add it in comments.

Comment: sorry that is easier, updated

Comment: What is `local.epga`? Can you make the question with all relevant details? It would be much faster then asking for them, one by one.

Comment: Sorry had to step away, appreciate your patience, will update all details later tonight.